# Escaping Dollar Sign Inside Snowflake Javascript Stored Procedure within Terraform

Tags: terraform, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, terraform0.12+

I am trying to incorporate Stored Procedure written in Javascript into Terraform for Snowflake, when I tried to apply script as it was developed I was getting bellow error:

```
A reference to a resource type must be followed by at least one attribute access, specifying the resource name
```

Based on the line numbers which raised the error message it does not like the dollar sign, so it seems like it needs to get escaped, example of such un-altered lines are below:

```
if (rowCount == 0) return `Error: Script with SCRIPT_TYPE = ${SCRIPT_TYPE} and  ACCES_TYPE = ${ACCES_TYPE} does not exist.`;
```

```
var sql =  `select PARAMETER_NAMES, TEMPLATE from administration.utils.SCRIPT_TEMPLATE where SCRIPT_TYPE = ''${SCRIPT_TYPE}'' AND ACCES_TYPE = ''${ACCES_TYPE}''`
```

What I am after is to know how to escape it and have this logic using the `replace` function incorporated in procedure resource creation `resource "snowflake_procedure"` as to be seen below, so that any future changes to the logic or introduction of new procedures does not have to be manually altered, my attempt was to use `'\$'` for escaping in the function, however not successful:

```
resource "snowflake_procedure" "GENERATE_SCRIPT_FROM_TEMPLATE" {
  name     = "GENERATE_SCRIPT_FROM_TEMPLATE"
  database = "ADMINISTRATION"
  schema   = "UTILS"
  language = "JAVASCRIPT"
  arguments {
    SCRIPT_TYPE = "arg1"
    type = "VARCHAR(250)"
  }
  arguments {
    ACCES_TYPE = "arg2"
    type = "VARCHAR(250)"
  }
  arguments {
    PARAMETER_VALUES = "arg3"
    type = "VARCHAR(5000)"
  }  
  return_type         = "VARCHAR"
  execute_as          = "OWNER"
  statement           = replace(
        <<EOT
  try
  {
    var parameterValues = JSON.parse(PARAMETER_VALUES);
  }
  catch (err)  {
    return `Failed to parse PARAMETER_VALUES: ${PARAMETER_VALUES}. Correct format is: {"DATABASE": "ADMINISTRATOR", "SCHEMA": "UTILS"}.`;
  }
   var sql =  `select PARAMETER_NAMES, TEMPLATE from administration.utils.SCRIPT_TEMPLATE where SCRIPT_TYPE = ''${SCRIPT_TYPE}'' AND ACCES_TYPE = ''${ACCES_TYPE}''`
   var stmt = snowflake.createStatement({ sqlText: sql });                
   var result = stmt.execute();
   var rowCount = result.getRowCount();
   if (rowCount == 0) return `Error: Script with SCRIPT_TYPE = ${SCRIPT_TYPE} and  ACCES_TYPE = ${ACCES_TYPE} does not exist.`;
   result.next();
   var parameterNames = result.getColumnValue(1);
   var scriptTemplate = result.getColumnValue(2);
   var parameterNamesArray = parameterNames.split('','');
   parameterNamesArray.forEach(parameterName => {
     if (!parameterValues[parameterName]) return `Failed: Cannot find parameter ${parameterName} in PARAMETER_VALUES: ${PARAMETER_VALUES}.`
   });
   var oldStrimg = '''';
   var newString = '''';
   var script = scriptTemplate;
   parameterNamesArray.forEach(parameterName => {
     oldStrimg = `<${parameterName}>`;
     newString = parameterValues[parameterName];
     script = script.replace(oldStrimg,newString);
   });
   return script;
EOT
, "$", "'\$'")
}
```

Comment: Have you tried adding an additional $ in front of all variables that require substitution?

Answer (score 0):

What I did to escape $$ was to use another sign

For example (sql scripting)

```
let q := $$ ... ## something ## $$
q := replace(:q, '##', '$$')
```